# How do you launch an iOS app in the current device orientation?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, ios8

I'm working with Xamarin and am having troubles launching my app in the current device orientation.

I have a UINavigationController that I set on my main UIWindow as the root controller. I created a custom UINavigationController which overrides the methods : 
GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations
and
ViewWillTransitionToSize

If I hold my iPad in landscape mode and start the app, it will start in portrait mode and then rotate in landscape. I'd like to make it start in the same orientation as the device's physical orientation. From the doc I've read it seems that since iOS 8, everything related to rotations should be handled in the root uiview controller which is my custom UINavigationController.

And here's my problem... let's say I want to start my app in the current device's orientation and then block everything except Portrait once the app is loaded. I tried the 2 following solutions and none worked.

1- I put all interface orientations available in the supported interface orientations key in the info.plist file. I launched the app while holding the iPad in landscape mode. In this case, my app starts in the same orientation as the device which is cool. What is not cool is that it doesn't call my navigation controller method GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations anymore. So even if I change the return value of that method to Portrait only later one, it does absolutely nothing since the method is never called anymore.

2- I removed all supported interface orientations from the info.plist file. I lauched the app while holding the iPad in landscape mode. In this case, my app starts in portrait mode and then rotates to landscape. I want to prevent the rotation and just start the app in the current device's orientation (landscape). With this setup though, I can later change the supported orientation as the navigation controller method GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations  is being called everytime we try to rotate the app.

In [apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller), it says "At launch time, apps should always set up their interface in a portrait orientation. After the application (_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) method returns, the app uses the view controller rotation mechanism described above to rotate the views to the appropriate orientation prior to showing the window."

The part where the view rotates to the appropriate orientation **PRIOR** to showing the window doesn't seem to work for me. It shows the window and then rotates it after.

So how do you launch an app in the current device's orientation (without the user seeing your first view rotate from portrait to whatever) and then be able to change the supported orientations later in the app? Example : I hold my iPad in landscape mode. I launch my app. First view I see is already in landscape mode. I can then rotate my iPad to change the view in portrait/landscape back and forth. Then I click a button which changes the supported orientation to Portrait which prevents me from changing the orientation to Landscape anymore.

Thanks!

Comment: As additional info, I use a UINavigationController as my UIWindow root view controller. I also tried to add a delegate to my UINavigationController to override the delegate's supportedUIInterfaceOrientation method but it never gets called like the other methods when you add supported interface orientations in the info.plist file...

Comment: `GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations()` can be called for your solution 1. And you can try difference `UIInterfaceOrientationMask` to test it.